# Bathtub Death Betting

Tags: probability

A rather grim question if you ask me but the question goes as follows:

Each year, about 300 Americans drown in their bathtubs. Which of the options should you choose:

A: win \$100 if no bathtubs deaths occur tomorrow

B: win \$100 if exactly 1 bathtub death occurs tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of deaths in a given day is Poisson distributed with mean $$\lambda = 300/365 = 60/73$$.  The distribution has 
$$p(k;\lambda) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$

So which is larger, 
$$
\frac{(60/73)^0}{0!} = 1
$$
or
$$
\frac{(60/73)^1}{1!} = (60/73) 
$$

I would bet on no bathtub deaths tomorrow.

Comment: Why is it Poisson?

Comment: never mind. figured it out. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Of course this assumes that bathtub deaths are equally likely to occur on any day of the year.  I don't know of any data on American bathing habits, but I doubt that this is the case.  In particular, I would guess that there are considerable differences between weekdays, weekends and holidays.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so we know that there are $300$ deaths in bathtub per year,assuming the year has 365 days,  by the stars and bars method there are $\binom{664}{300}$ ways to distribute these deaths around the year.

If we know there are zero deaths in a given day then we must distribute the $300$ deaths in only $364$ days, thus there are $\binom{663}{300}$ ways to do it by the stars and bars method.

On the other hand if there is exactly one death in the given day we must distribute the remaining $299$ deaths into $364$ days, so there are $\binom{662}{299}$.

The probability of the first is therefore $\dfrac{\binom{663}{300}}{\binom{664}{300}}\approx54.8\%$

the probability of the second is $\dfrac{\binom{662}{299}}{\binom{664}{300}}\approx24.8\%$

Comment: One flaw in this reasoning is that these ways are not equally likely. Deaths are not indistinguishable.  "I die today and you die tomorrow" is not the same as "You die today and I die tomorrow".

Comment: I don't see what the difference is for the results

Comment: For example, if there were two deaths in two days, your method would make the probability  that both deaths are on the same day $2/3$, while the correct probability would be $1/2$.